# populate a dropdown in grails

Tags: grails, dropdown

i have a user that i give a role to it, and i want when i create the user, to show the roles in a dropdown, then i can select the role that i want to give to him, how can i do it ?? please i really need help in it, cause im new in grails here is the **user.groovy**

```
class User {

transient securiteService

String username
String password
String nom
String prenom
String email
String tel

static hasMany = [roles : Role]

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false,display: false
    nom nullable: true
    prenom nullable: true
    email email:true, nullable:true
    tel nullable:true, maxSize:20,  matches:/[\+]{0,1}[0-9\s]{3,15}/
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
    sort nom: "asc"
    affectations sort : "dateAffectation", order:"desc"
    intervention sort : "responsable", order:"desc"
}
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? and explain the complete flow how and where you want to populate the dropdown?

Comment: @NitinDhomse i didn't try anything, cause first i don't know how to, i have the view create of the user, i want it to contain a dropdown that let me choose the role, knowing that the role has it's own domain class, does things get clear now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example will help you, make necessary changes in your code according to your need.
For example you have a table / domain Role

```
class Role {
   String roleId
   String roleName  // e.g ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

// Populate the dropdown in your GSP view ( this will populate all the roles present in the Role table)

```
<g:select from="${Role.list().roleName}" name="selectUserRole"
                                optionKey=""
                                optionValue=""/>
```

Comment: this error is showen i don't know why : Cannot invoke method list() on null object

Comment: Because your table is empty or domain class Role not imported in that gap, insert some records in the table

Comment: Your Role instance is getting null, have you imported that domain class?

Comment: like <%@ page import="com.temp.Role" %> or use from="${com.temp.Role.list().roleName}" temp is sample package name here

Comment: what if i wanted to save this role to that user how do i do it bro

Comment: If your have "has many" roles mapping then create List roles property in your User class.

Comment: and what do i do next ?

Comment: Save the List of roles or list with a single role in your user's save call e.g user is a object of class User then user.roles = ['role1'] then user.save(flush: true) or you can read value from params (from gsp to controller) and convert that to list of roles or a list of single role

Comment: i did this but it doesn't work :  def role = params.role
        respond new User(username: params.username, password: params.password, nom: params.nom, prenom: params.prenom, email: params.email, tel: params.tel, roles: role)

Comment: Declare List userRoles = [] then userRoles << params.role and pass userRoles to the User object as roles : userRoles, you could use multi select plug-in (jquery) to get multiple roles from dropdown and generate the list of those roles.

Comment: def create() {
        List userRole = []
        userRole = [params.role]
        respond new User(username: params.username, password: params.password, nom: params.nom, prenom: params.prenom, email: params.email, tel: params.tel, roles: userRole)
    }

Comment: i don't know, it makes me frustrated

Comment: No, insert as  userRole << params.role or using userRole.add( params.role), please explore yourself, put debugging statements like println if you have confusion, read grails / groovy docs

Comment: i did reading the docs, but, honestly its my first time working with a framework, i never studied MVC or framwork logic

Comment: Ask another question with what you have tried and expected result, I cant help more you in comments, I or somebody will help you with that